# Can alter the standard layout so links go to a VisualForce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I created a custom object called ImportBusiness__c. I added this to the standard Account page, so now, when you look at an Account, you also see any related ImportBusiness__c objects. I followed the advice here:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h3AeAAI

This worked great, but now, when you click on a ImportBusiness__c link, I go to a ImportBusiness__c page using the standard layout, the default. I actually want to go to a custom VisualForce page. Is there any way I can alter what the default link goes to?

[ [ UPDATE  ] ]

With this Visualforce page tag:

```
<apex:page standardController="ImportBusiness__c"     extensions="ImportBusinessController" id="ImportBusinessView">
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown constructor     'ImportBusinessController.ImportBusinessController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do so depending on your end goal

1. You can create a link field on the custom object that links to your Visualforce page and add this field to the account page layout related list. [Reference](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000glfGAAQ)
2. If you always want the view record of the ImportBusiness__c to be a Visualforce page, you can override the view page. [Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000094LYIAY)
3. If your visualforce page is generic and not related to specific record of the Import business record you can just add a related list button.

Comment: It sounds like I want option #2, but your link doesn't say how to override the default page that I go to.

Comment: This is a bit more onpoint: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_tabs.htm

Comment: Let me know if you need further help on this.

Comment: Actually, I can't do this step: "For Override With select Visualforce Page."

Comment: I click "Override" but the dropdown, which should list my VisualForce pages, is empty. And yet I have 8 VisualForce pages, and I have used them in my browser.

Comment: So ImportBusiness__c would have to be an extension of Account?

Comment: At this point I simply want to replace the default layout one sees when one goes to see a ImportBusiness__c object.

Comment: Searching a sample code ... hold on

Comment: Your visualforce page should have StandardController="ImportBusiness__c" extension="other classes that have custom logic"
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_customize_override.htm

Comment: Another sample code https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gzURAAY

Comment: The controller should have the same name as the custom class? That seems likely to confuse.

Comment: the controller of the Visualforce page needs to be an extension of the standard controller of the custom object. More on controller extension here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm

Comment: Not allowed! I tried to create a new Apex class called "ImportBusiness__c" and I got the error message: "Invalid identifier: ImportBusiness__c"

Comment: again this is not the name of the class ... this is just the controller of the page. The class itself needs special kind of constructor and the page needs to use this controller as extension. Have a look on the links in my last 2 comments

Comment: The controller is a class, I thought? What is the difference between a controller and a class?

Comment: If I go to edit my custom object, and I click on ImportBusiness Tab, then it allows me to choose any VisualForce page. But not when I click on "View". And I'd like to override the default view.

Comment: I define the constructor as:     public ImportBusinessController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
               but this does not help.

Comment: Tabs doesn't require any restriction on the controller of the page. Your page should have the below tag
<apex:page standardController="ImportBusiness__c" extensions="ImportBusinessController">
You will need to adjust the code in ImportBusinessController accordingly

Comment: Now I get an error "Unknown constructor 'ImportBusinessController.ImportBusinessController()'"

Comment: Okay, interesting bit about the "extension"

Comment: if you reread the links in previous comments it will make sense ... specially the case example.

Comment: Now I get this error: "The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must begin with a letter and be unique, and must not include spaces, end with an underscore, or contain two consecutive underscores."

Comment: If I remove "__c" I'm told "The class ImportBusiness does not exist".

Comment: What is the controller suppose to be? What should I put for a controller? Is that not a custom Apex class?

Comment: Standard controller ... is not a custom apex class it is the name of the object with __c at the end. Controller extension is an apex class with some properties as per the help link i sent in earlier comment.

Comment: With this Visualforce page tag:

<apex:page standardController="ImportBusiness__c" extensions="ImportBusinessController" id="ImportBusinessView">

I get this error: 

Unknown constructor 'ImportBusinessController.ImportBusinessController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'

Comment: Hmm, for some reason Salesforce isn't saving my new version of the custom controller. I've been waiting for 40 minutes. Perhaps everything will work when that goes through.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47428/discussion-on-answer-by-amr-ibrahim-can-alter-the-standard-layout-so-links-go-to).